# Service is stopping when another program exits

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services

I have a service and made a small program that monitors the service and restarts it if it goes down...

my problem is, that if I close the monitor program, then the service stops, and I can't figure out why...

my program looks as following

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var sc = new ServiceController("Explore");
                var client = new HttpClient();

                while (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 8 &&
                       DateTime.Now <= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 59))
                {
                    sc.Refresh();
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped && sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Paused)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(300000);
                        continue;
                    }

                    sc.Start();
                    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
                    sc.Refresh();

                    // starts services that handle notifications
                    await client.GetAsync($"{host}/sqltorabbit/start");
                    await client.GetAsync($"{host}/notifications/indexer/Elastic/start");
                    await client.GetAsync($"{host}/notifications/push/Apple/start");
                }

                await Task.Delay(28800000);
            }).Wait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you host it? Azure? IIS? They both will recycle your app under certain conditions (memory pressure, idle time) etc. that's normal behavior of IIS so don't rely on your app always being up. If you need something that runs all the time, run it as background process, i.e. separate exe hosted/running outside of IIS

Comment: The service is hosted on my own machine, and is a console that starts a owin WebApp, so I shouldn't worry about iis recycle either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was elsewhere...

When the code startet the service, it couldn't connect to the database on windows credentials... but if set log on as a specific account on the service, the it works...